# Python why does my defined function which output is a list keep receiving nonetype error

Tags: python, list, function, nonetype

I define a function which output is to print a list.
then i want to compare that list with len(l2) which is some other list in my code but i keep receiving this error that my defined function's output is a NoneType and it cant be compared with integers how can i solve this problem? Im new to programming so please answer simply

```
l = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    x = int(input())
    l.append(x)
def prime_counter(n):
    b = 1
    l1 = []
    while b <= n:
        k = 0
        if n % b == 0:
            j = 1
            while j <= b:
                if b % j == 0:
                    k = k + 1
                j = j + 1
            if k == 2:
                l1.append(b)
        b = b + 1
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    l2 = []
    if len(prime_counter(l[i])) > len(l2):
        l2.extend(prime_counter(l[i]))
print(l2)
```

Comment: But where is the function?Add it to the code

Comment: You weren't very clear what is going on but what it sounds like to me is you are trying to get the len of the function for example `print(len(some_func()))` but you are not returning anything from the function so by default None is returned. You need to post some code so we can see.

Comment: Your function contains no `return` yet you use it with `len`. You should add `return l1` at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have any `return` statement in a function, `None` is returned automatically. So, you need to return some object from a function that the caller of the function can use further.

This is happening in your `prime_counter` function; you're supposed to return the `l1` list from it but you're returning nothing warranting `len(None)` which would error out as `None` singleton does not have any length associated with it.

You need to return the `l1` list from `prime_counter`:

```
def prime_counter(n):
    b = 1
    l1 = []
    while b <= n:
        ...
        ...
    return l1
```